# Not winning the competition was disappointing to/for us

Tags: prepositions, for

> Not winning the competition was disappointing to us.

The above sentence is correct, but it kept me wondering if we can use 'for' instead of 'to'.

(source: [courses.edx.org](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UQx+Write101x+1T2017/courseware/fc0a8eb7ad1d47ff878c1732c948dbd0/059fce5a1d0e448eafe41cf0ab248326/?activate_block_id=block-v1%3AUQx%2BWrite101x%2B1T2017%2Btype%40sequential%2Bblock%40059fce5a1d0e448eafe41cf0ab248326))

Comment: Yes you can. They have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I think : 
"Not winning the competition was disappointing FOR us."
BUT 
"losing the competition was disappointing FOR/TO us."

I have no idea why, but the latter could work both ways, the former only the one way.